# matlab readfile with numbers

Tags: arrays, matlab, readfile

In general I'm defining a matlab fnction which takes the name of a file containing some numbers, one per line, reads the data in, and then returns the data in an array.

```
function x = readdata(filename)

This function takes the name of a file contained in the
% character array "filename", read in the data from it, and then
% return the resulting numbers in the 1-dimensional array x. The
% array x can be n x 1 or 1 x n, where n is the number of numbers
% in the data file.
%
% If the data file cannot be found, this function should print a
% warning (using the disp() function) and return x as an empty
% array. If the data file can be found but is empty or contains
% only comments (lines starting with the Matlab comment indicator %),
% this function should return an empty array x with no warning
% message.
%
%

%I'm not sure how to check if a file exist (while they are in same folder).
%I tried if exist(filename,'file') but this is not working
```

This is what I have now:

```
function x = readdata(file)
fid = fopen(file);
tline = fgets(fid);
while isnumeric(tline)
disp(tline)
tline = fgets(fid)
```

Thanks

Comment: When you tried `exist(filename,'file')`, what actually was not working ? What did you expect ? Do you have an error message ?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by taking a look at the documentation that you could find [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html#f5-6402) for reading in line-by-line.  It even gives a sample code that you could start with:

> ### Reading Data Line-by-Line
>
> MATLAB provides two functions that read lines from files and store them in
>   string vectors: `fgetl` and `fgets`. The `fgets` function copies the newline 
>   character to the output string, but `fgetl` does not.
>
> The following example uses fgetl to read an entire file one line at a time. 
>   The function `litcount` determines whether an input literal string (literal) 
>   appears in each line. If it does, the function prints the entire line preceded 
>   by the number of times the literal string appears on the line.
>
> ```
> function y = litcount(filename, literal)
> % Search for number of string matches per line.  
>
> fid = fopen(filename);
> y = 0;
> tline = fgetl(fid);
> while ischar(tline)
>    matches = strfind(tline, literal);
>    num = length(matches);
>    if num > 0
>       y = y + num;
>       fprintf(1,'%d:%s\n',num,tline);
>    end
>    tline = fgetl(fid);
> end
> fclose(fid);
> ```

You should be able to replace what is inside the `while` loop with what you are looking to do.

Of note is that the `fgets` and `fgetl` functions return character arrays (strings).  Thus, you'll need to first check whether the line is a comment, and then, if not, convert the string to a numeric value using something along the lines of `str2double`.

As for checking existence of a file, `exist(filename,'file')` is definitely what you want. Its documentation is found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html?searchHighlight=exist).
You should be able to do something like:

```
if ~exist(filename,'file')
    % Do something... I suggest the warning function, disp could be used too... 
    warning('The file cannot be found!')
    return
end
```